# How do I display an embedded image from an object in an aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have an object with an embedded image accessible as a property e.g. myObject.image.  This image is a Gif that is stored as an embedded resource in the dll.  On my aspx source I have a .net image control.  This control essentially spits out a standard html image element that needs an image url as a source.  So how do I make this thing display my image property from my object?  I can't simply say myHTMLImageElement = myObject.image.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: if you base64 encode your image, you can use data URI for image source - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: I think I found a good solution.  My embedded image exposes a "save" method.  So I just point my asp.net Image control to a filename and call myObject.Image.Save(Server.MapPath(".") + "\\myImage.gif") on pageload.

Comment: are you expecting this location in your website to be writable for your code?

Comment: It is writable for my code, yes, but that's certainly a legitimate consideration and reason enough to want to learn to do this in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `MemoryStream` class to hold the bytes of image.

```
using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
{
    myObject.image.Save(m, image.RawFormat); //u can use System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg or whatever ur image type is
    ...
}
```

Then you can convert the `byte` data into `Base64String` format and assign it to your `<img>` element.

write the following code in same `using` statement given above after `myObject.image.Save` line.

```
string strBase64 = System.String.ToBase64String(m.ToArray());
myImg.Attributes["src"] = strBase64;
```

make sure you have set the `runat='server'` in your img tag.

Comment: This certainly seems like a more elegant solution, but it isn't working for me.  First there didn't seem to be a ToBase64String() in System.String (at least in the version 4 framework) so I googled around converting memorystream to base64 string and found Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray()).  So I do that then set the src attribute to strBase64 as you say, but the result doesn't display the graphic, and when I view the source of the page the src attribute of the image is set to lots of junk that looks like encoded characters, but it doesn't translate them into my image.